# jquery / ajax feed parser script not working on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, rss

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(function () {
      url = 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/us_and_canada/rss.xml?fmt=xml';
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=1000&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
          dataType: 'json',
          error: function () {
              alert('Unable to load feed, Incorrect path or invalid feed');
          },
          success: function (xml) {
              values = xml.responseData.feed.entries;
              $.each(values, function (i) {
                  $('#results').append('<h1>' + values[i].title + '</h1>');
                  $('#results').append(values[i].content);
              });

          }
      });
  });
});
```

The above code works fine in my [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuhgenc6/38/) - but when implemented it consistently goes to the error `alert()` function

**And my console reports:** *(reports the below locally, and live server)*

*XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/us_and_canada/rss.xml?format=xml. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
home.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://bsnm.s3.amazonaws.com/IVC/103b8b081e0c4ee0ef0d57d45ed11104. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.*

Comment: Can you add an `err` parameter to the error function and alert the `err.message`?

Comment: Is `document.location.protocol` `https:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some odd reason - the issue was this:

```
url: document.location.protocol +
```

When I replace '`document.location.protocol`' with actual `http:` it works fine.

I was loading jQuery v 3.1 - not sure if that matters. If anyone has insight as to *why* or the reason for this, please add to my answer!

*ie.* below now works.

```
url: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=1000&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this bug on my local box using jQuery v1.1.1 but it loads fine when I try jQuery v2.1.1.

Are you using an old version of jQuery?

Note: The code I tested locally is exactly the same as your jsFiddle except I changed 
`document.location.protocol` to `'http://'` 
and added `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>`